# Firebase hosting: Why firebase hosted my all the source code into there hosting? How can I restrict only to "build" folder?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting

I have build a react app and I used firebase hosting to deploy my app. It's working fine but firebase has hosted all the source code. I only need to upload build folder. How can I remove other files from the hosting?

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Is there any thing to do?

But somehow I have uploaded build folder only for another app But I cannot remember/find how I did it, I see no different between firebase.json

[image]

firebase,json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have map files in `build/static` folder. Those files will re-generate the source files. So we can re-deploy the website after deleting `.map` files or change the `firebase.json` file.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**", "**/**/*.map"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood the things. Firebase has hosted only your build folder.[image].

The above image shows the files for my react keep clone. The ts files and src folder are not generated explicitly and I am sure that your entire code has not been hosted.

Comment: No brother. https://imgur.com/a/0CgUPbw this is my other project. It's ok but here it's not. the folder has all the things when compare with my local build folder. I deploy several times but it's not working!

Comment: @Lakpriya Senevirathna What was the exact solution? I can also see my all of my source code in the Sources tab...

Comment: @studio-pj no i still have the issue!, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @studio-pj question updated! pls check, thank you!